# Why would I need to str_replace \t tabs and \n new lines in wp_mail()?

Tags: wordpress, wp-mail

Check out this simple snippet, which is a "solution" I think I should not have to do... but maybe I am wondering if that IS what ya have to do when using `wp_mail()` these days?

```
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n'; 
$message = str_replace("\\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $message); 
$message = str_replace("\\n", "<br />", $message); 
$message = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $message); 
$message = str_replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $message); 
                
wp_mail( $send_to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments  );
```

Turns out, that's what I have to do to make the following work as expected, which seems really odd to me... Any ideas why? Plugins are shut off, this is just a little hook in a function to send an email to an admin when certain conditions are met.

If I do NOT do `str_replace`, then this is the content of the email [below], it literally shows the new line and tab operators. lol, yuk.

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"

Admin Notice:\n
\t\t This thing happened, [link]
```

If I do NOT do `str_replace`, then this is the html content of the email, again showing new line and tab operators. lol, also yuk

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

<p>Admin Notice:\n<br />
\t\t This thing happened, [link]</p>
```

The body content of that email text is stored in a theme-option textarea. The default of that textarea contains `\t\t`, but when I save the value it becomes `\\t\\t`, hence those 4x lazy `str_replace` functions.

Ultimately, `str_replace` "works" but I just can not help but think I am missing something here or there is another problem I am not seeing...

If this is indeed "how its done" in `wp_mail()` let me know...

Surprisingly, none of these do the trick either...

```
$message = str_replace("\\t", "\t", $message); // not work
$message = rawurldecode($message); // not work
$message = htmlentities($message); // not work
$message = nl2br($message); // uh uh
$message = stripcslashes($message); // not work
$message = htmlspec($message); // nope
$message = wordwrap($message); // not the droid im lookn4
```

Whats interesting here is this works, when I shove some `\r\n\t\t` up in that header...

```
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n';
```

Just... does not work in the `wp_mail($message)` - odd...

Comment: It's possible that escape sequences such as **\t** could work with *text/plain*. But, they probably have to be escaped multiple times depending on the number of times it is unescaped as it is processed by wp_mail(). You could experiment with increasing numbers of backslashes until it works. Or, try PHP_EOL for newlines and **chr()** for tabs and other non-printing characters.

Comment: interesting... I think its 2x or 3x, because str_replace("\\t") seemed to do the trick... have you run into this before in WordPress? I wonder if there is a hook in the theme doing it... just thought it was odd that I would have to str_replace this. Never have to do that with PHPmailer... and that is what WP is using...

Comment: I've run into this problem with other functions (quadruple or higher backslashing needed). With wp_mail() I use HTML. So, HTML elements and PHP_EOL are all I use for spacing.

Comment: @kofeigen how did you determine how many backslashings were needed to be removed? when I dump the output I see what you mean, it seems to me there are // 2x I need to remove, however, its as if... there are additional backslashes I am not seeing. I wonder its because I am debugging this by sending myself an email... maybe I need to get up into that hook and var_dump it all out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did a test with **[wp_mail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)** using these header settings:

```
'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'
'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable'

('Content-Transfer-Encoding: bit-8' also worked)
```

A single backslash within double quotes `("\t")` was sufficient to render the tab character.

Be careful that you are not using the [wp_mail_content_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_content_type/) filter hook to set the content type to HTML.

If you send **text-only** content while using the **text/html** mime type (either using a Header or wp_mail_content_type), the tab characters can appear to be stripped out by the email client.

When using text/html, the tab characters will be sent to the email server and client. If you open the email to view the raw content (e.g. View Source option in Thunderbird), you will see that the tab characters are there. Some email clients style plain text emails and display them using HTML. Since HTML collapses contiguous space characters, the display appears to have stripped out the tabs.

### Headers

Below, are all the headers I used:

```
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "From: ${from}";
$headers[] = "Sender: ${from}";
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';
$headers[] = 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: bit-8';
$headers[] = 'Content-Language: ' . $locale;
```